# JDBC MySQL perfomance speed up

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I'm writing test and i want to make drop database and recreate database as tear-down phase in every test. I have a .sql file with sql script which makes what i need (drop DB and recreate it. DB is hosted on local PC). When i pass that .sql file into mysql command line console it runs very fast (btw, .sql script has around 800 strings). When i pass it throw mysql.jdbc it goes 10x slower.

I'm thinking of calling cmd procedure and pass mysql console command to cmd to execute my script file.

Can anyone suggest more elegant solution?

Comment: It would probably be helpful is how show your code that is executing the script via JDBC, since that is what you should be asking us to help optimize.

Comment: Could you use an in-memory database such as HSQLDB for executing your tests? Things would probably run smoother.

Comment: That's quite a difference in performance. Can you show the code you use to execute the script? Do you see any errors?